# Salesforce Trigger Test

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I created the following class that updates the Websites field after a new website is added. It basically normalises it by removing 'http://', 'https://', and 'www'.

Here's the class:

```
trigger standardiseWebsitesTrigger on Account (after insert, after update ) {
if(checkRecursive.runOnce()){

    Set<Id> AccIds = new Set<Id>();

    List<Account> acctsToUpdate = new List<Account>{};


        for (Account acc : Trigger.new){
            AccIds.add(acc.Id);
        }

    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Website FROM Account WHERE Id IN :AccIds];

    for (Account acc : accounts){
        string website = acc.Website;
        string hostDomain1 = 'http://';
        string hostDomain2 = 'https://';
        string justWWWAddress = 'www';       

        if (acc.Website.startsWith(hostDomain1) || acc.Website.startsWith(hostDomain2) && acctsToUpdate.isEmpty()){
            Url u = new Url(acc.Website);
            website = u.GetHost();
            acc.Website = u.getHost().replaceFirst('^(https?://www\\.|https?://|www\\.)','');
            acctsToUpdate.add(acc);

        }

        if(acc.Website.startsWith(justWWWAddress) && acctsToUpdate.isEmpty()){
            acc.website = website.substring(4);
            acctsToUpdate.add(acc);

        }

        update acctsToUpdate; 

    }
}

}
```

However when using the following test the assertion relating to removing the 'www.' component fails:

```
@isTest
public class standardiseWebsitesTriggerTest {

static testmethod void standardiseWebsiteTriggerHTTP() {
    testSetup('HTTP', 'http://I_AM_HTTP', true);
}

static testmethod void standardiseWebsitesTriggerWWW() {
    testSetup('WWW', 'WWW.I_AM_WWW', false);
}

public static void testSetup(String accName, String accWebsite, Boolean webProtocol) {
    Account acc = new Account(
        Name = accName,
        Website = accWebsite
    );
    insert acc;

    Account updatedAccount = [select Website from Account where id = :acc.Id];

    if(webProtocol) {
        Url u = new Url(acc.Website);
        System.assert(u.getHost() == updatedAccount.Website);
    } else {
        System.assert(updatedAccount.Website == acc.Website.substring(4));
    }
}
}
```

The error is:

> Assertion failed
>   Class.standardiseWebsitesTriggerTest.testSetup: line 25, column 1
>   Class.standardiseWebsitesTriggerTest.standardiseWebsitesTriggerWWW: line 9, column 1

Any idea as to why this test may be failing?

Comment: presumably you meant to use `startsWithIgnoreCase()` instead of `startsWith()` [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_startsWith)

Comment: You should prefer using System.assertEquals instead of System.assert; this would give you a more meaningful error message: `System.assertEquals(acc.Website.substring(4), updatedAccount.Website);` This would let you see what the values were.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has quite a number of code quality problems, most of which were not uncovered because your unit test fails to take into account various scenarios.

## DML inside loop

Don't put a DML operation inside a loop.

## Useless query

Trigger.new already has Website available, so there's no need to query the accounts again.

## Recursive Updates

Using after update means that the record already being updated will be updated again. This results in an error. Use before insert/before update instead. I realize you're checking to avoid recursion, but it still doesn't matter; this code won't work the way you expect.

## Won't Work Correctly on All URLs

You're not replacing "www.domain.com" correctly; it only works if there's a protocol.

## Some Sites May Require WWW

Removing a leading WWW might result in unusable links. In the best case scenario, if you use this URL elsewhere, you might get 302 redirects, or it might simply fail to load altogether. This is dependent on the DNS entries. I realize this is 2017, and all major sites helpfully redirect for you, but not all sites do. This is simply a caution, ignore it at your own risk.

## NullPointerException

String.startsWith throws an exception if a value is null. You'd want to check this first.

---

Here's an optimized version of your trigger:

```
trigger standardiseWebsitesTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {
    for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.Website != null) {
            record.Website = record.Website.removeStartIgnoreCase('https://');
            record.Website = record.Website.removeStartIgnoreCase('http://');
            record.Website = record.Website.removeStartIgnoreCase('www.');
        }
    }
}
```

---

As for your unit test, make sure you're testing non-positive conditions as well; what happens when website is null? What happens when someone feeds in an FTP protocol address? Make sure you also test large amounts of records (typically, it would be recommended to test 201 records, but this may not always be possible). This makes sure that when the trigger runs more than once, it still operates as expected.